Python - SQL Alchemy - Closing Program Error
My Problem
I'm having some strange problems when exiting a discord bot which uses the ASync version of SQL Alchemy.
I've stripped out all the functionality so I'm left with the simple process:

Bot Connects
DB Connects
I shutdown Bot Gracefully
Error is thrown

I'm still getting use to ASync in python so I apologise in advance if I asking something stupid here... Whenever I await the "service_shutdown" function I get the error suggested below.
Python 3.11
I'm Using SqlAlchemy with aiomysql
My Code
```
########## Async DB Connection ########

db_url = config["maindatabase"]["url"]
async_bot_engine = create_async_engine(db_url)

async_session = sessionmaker(
    bind=async_bot_engine,
    class_=AsyncSession,
    expire_on_commit=False,
)

Base = declarative_base()

async def close_connections():
    await async_bot_engine.dispose(close=True)

####### Discord Event Handler for Bot Disconnect ######
def register_shutdown(client: discord.Client) -> None:
    @client.event
    async def on_disconnect():
        await db.close_connections()
        return


####### Discord Event Handler for Bot Disconnect ######
async def service_shutdown(message: discord.Message, client:discord.Client) -> None:
    await message.channel.send("Disconnecting...")
    await client.close()

```

### My Error Message ###
```
Exception ignored in: <function Connection.__del__ at 0x7fa474e900e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bot/botv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 1131, in __del__
  File "/home/bot/botv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 339, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 831, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 758, in call_soon
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 519, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Tried so Far...

I've read no end of threads on the specific "line 1131, in del" part but there doesn't seem to be anything the way of a concrete solution described.

I've also tried moving the await "close_connections" function to the on disconnect event handler built into discord as shown to see if this was an order of execution issue etc., but exactly the same error every time both ways around.

It would be awesome if someone could point me in the direction of a fix here. Primarily because I'm concerned I'm not understanding the documentation etc. correctly!


Big Thank You in advance.

Are you closing your sessions / connections in your code? engine.dispose will only close connections that are not checked out of the connection pool.

@snakecharmerb - Thank you for your reply. I started tweaking a few random functions here in what I thought was an unrelated area. The error disspeared. I've been through the commits several times and cannot work out what the hell caused it, or caused the error to go. I've not seen it since either.
I'm new as mentioned but I appreciate 'Vodoo Magic' is rare in software engineering and so it was definetly something I did... the mystery continues.
Thank you for the additional context on the sessions though, it's very helpful to know that learning what I am.
